# How to fix the code: Copy-Paste Cell Comment to Another Cell via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I finde some code it's not bad ↴

```
Sub Comments2cells()
Dim c As Range, n, m, r
  Set c = Selection.Find("*", Selection.Cells(Selection.Cells.Count), xlComments, , xlByRows, xlNext)
  If c Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "There are no comments in the selected range", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  On Error Resume Next
  Set n = Application.InputBox("Click the column to insert", Type:=8)
  If Err Then
    MsgBox "The range of inserts is not selected", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  n = n.Column
  Do
    If c.Row <> r Then r = c.Row: m = n Else m = m + 1
    Cells(r, m) = c.Comment.Text
    c.Comment.Delete
    Set c = Selection.FindNext(c)
  Loop Until c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

- How to change the code so that I can:

  1. I wont to Copy-Paste only Comment ↵ (with red indicator) from one cell to another 'without mashing the text in the cell itself'.
  2. How to insert not only a single cell but to be able to select multiple cells hold down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and insert in any cell?

[image]

---

**P.S.** ··· The code above inserts text from the Сomment into the cell itself. I don't need that.

---

No no no! This is not what i want!
I decided to edit my question to make it more clear!
The code I shared...

- In the first place! After runing the code, we see a form which appears to select the cell range to insert some Comment. Look at 21 second [screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/ErNY1AgSBo1u)!

  1. Copies Comment from cell, then removes the Comment from the cell (I don't need to remove).
  2. After he puts text to cell (i need to insert text to cell's Comment).

*Help correct the code please!*

Comment: @TimStack Hello! It's not duplicate! I find `code` on this [site](http://www.cyberforum.ru/visual-basic/thread2351454.html#post13059964)

Comment: 0Key i find some relevant Add-in called [Ablebits](https://www.ablebits.com/excel-addins.php). This Add-in includes `Comments Manager` it's really cool, [look](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2019/06/28/0002/1030/156678/78/6158c3c7c4.jpg). Instructions also [here](https://www.ablebits.com/excel-comments-manager/index.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim strCom As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Method 1
        'Ger the comment from A1
        strCom = .Range("A1").Comment.Text
        'Import the comment in A2
        .Range("A2").AddComment strCom
        'Method 2
        'Copy paste the comment
        .Range("A1").Copy
        .Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteComments
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try copying the whole source cell and then pasting only the comment to the destination cell:

```
Sub copyComment()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim destRng As Range
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your Worksheet")
    Set srcRng = sht.Range("A1")
    Set destRng = sht.Range("B1")
    srcRng.Copy
    destRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteComments

End Sub
```